# Using c# linq, in a where clause only include results from previous where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am wanting to only get the SourceEndpointConfigs from the sourceEndpoints retrieved from _vwSourceEndpoints. I am not sure how to modify my where clause to get the correct results. All help appreciated. Thanks!

```cs
_vwSourceEndpoints = db.vwSourceEndpoints
    .Where(e => e.StudySourceSystemId == study.StudySourceSystemId
            & e.ScheduleId == study.ScheduleId
            & e.OrderNo == study.OrderNo
            & e.Active == true
    ).ToList();


_vwSourceEndpointConfigs = db.SourceEndpointConfigs.Where(
    e => e.Active == true
    ).ToList();

var query3 = _vwSourceEndpointConfigs.Concat(_vwSourceEndpoints.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo).ToList();
```

I have come up with the below as an edit to my original code

```cs
_vwSourceEndpoints = db.vwSourceEndpoints.Where(
                    e => e.StudySourceSystemId == study.StudySourceSystemId
                    & e.ScheduleId == study.ScheduleId
                    & e.OrderNo == study.OrderNo
                    & e.Active == true).ToList();


                _vwSourceEndpointConfigs = db.SourceEndpointConfigs.Where(
                    e => _vwSourceEndpoints.All(x => x.StudySourceSystemId == study.StudySourceSystemId
                   & x.ScheduleId == study.ScheduleId
                   & x.OrderNo == study.OrderNo
                   & x.Active == true)
                    

                    ).ToList();
```

Comment: You should use the .Include() endpoint to join a related table.

Comment: use `join` keyword in single query

Comment: So put the query for _sourceEndpoint into the the Join()?

Comment: Show result entity, it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I am wanting to only get the sourceEndpointConfigs for the results retrieved on line 44

Comment: Edit your question and add result class definition.

Comment: I have edited my post. I believe I may have found the answer but mostly by plug and play.  Id like to know if I am doing the right thing here so I can become a better programmer. Thank you all for your hints in the right direction!!

Comment: Remove `.ToList()` from first query and second become translatable.

Answer (score 1):

If both tables have same columns you can use Union, if not select the columns that you want and then use Union.

```
var query = context.vwSourceEndpoints
                        .Where(e => e.StudySourceSystemId == study.StudySourceSystemId
                                && e.ScheduleId == study.ScheduleId
                                && e.OrderNo == study.OrderNo
                                && e.Active == true
                        ).Union(context.SourceEndpointConfigs.Where(e => e.Active == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is eventually what I found to be the best working solution.

```
_vwSourceEndpoints = db.vwSourceEndpoints.Where(
                    e => e.StudySourceSystemId == study.StudySourceSystemId
                    & e.ScheduleId == study.ScheduleId
                    & e.OrderNo == study.OrderNo
                    & e.Active == true).ToList();

                _vwSourceEndpointConfigs = (from config in db.SourceEndpointConfigs.Where(c => c.Active == true)
                                            join ep in _vwSourceEndpoints
                                            on config.SourceEndpointId equals ep.SourceEndpointId
                                            select config).ToList();
```